# How to change color below browser window to match footer

Tags: html, css, colors, background

Below I have a footer, it is a dark purple color.
[image: See here]
When I scroll past the end of the footer however, it is white. How do I change this white to match the footer color, without changing the background color of all the content I have up top?

I only want this color to show when a user attempts to scroll past the footer, not anywhere else in the document (or like when a user attempts to scroll above the nav for example).

Using `html {background-color: purple}` colors the entire document including the top, but I want this color only to show at the bottom.

Using `html {background: linear-gradient(white, purple)}` leaves a gradient stretched across my entire page but more importantly it shows up purple at the *top* and *white* at the bottom.

**Edit (better example)**

Consider https://codepen.io . Visit the homepage.
Now, when you attempt to scroll above the navigation bar, it shows a dark grayish color. When you attempt to scroll below the footer, it also shows a dark grayish color. Now what I want to do is show that color when a user scrolls past the *footer* only, not the navigation.

Comment: Hi there. In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Having said that, it **sounds** like you're looking for `body { margin: 0 }`, which makes sure the content is 'flush' against the edges, eliminating the whitespace.

Comment: No, it is flush against the edges. But when you reach _past_ the end of it, then you see the HTML whitespace.  Consider https://codepen.io. When you scroll _past_ the end of the footer, it is gray. I want to achieve this, *but* I only want the bottom to be that color not the top. Do you get it?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't. CodePen has **no** whitespace on it. It has a header, then a black section, followed by a grey section, then another black section. These are all independently defined and coloured sections. Simply define three sections, and set each one to have a background colour. You shouldn't rely on any content outside of a defined 'section'; if your 'flowover' content is simply sitting directly inside the `<body>`, give it its own `<div>`. However, as I say, you will need to provide your **code** for further help.

Comment: Lol, if the problem is that it's white at the bottom and purple at the top, why don't you just switch around the order of the parameters to `linear-gradient(purple, white)`?

Comment: @gendarme because this still leaves a gradient across my entire page

Comment: @cris you can try linear-gradient(purple 50%, white 50%)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Correct, it has no whitespace. That is not what I am talking about. Take stackoverflow's footer for example. When you attempt to scroll past the footer it is **white**. The footer is gray, but the HTML color below is white. That is not the case in codepen.io. When you scroll past the footer in codepen.io it is **not** white, it is gray.

Comment: @itodd this makes half of my page purple. It matches the footer color, but now half my page is purple.

Comment: @Cris -- You're not supposed to be able to scroll past the footer on StackOverflow **or** CodePen. It sounds like you're using a **mobile phone** and talking about the inherent 'swing' effect where you can scroll past. This comes from the `<body>` colour.

Comment: No this happens on mobile and desktop, in which case I don't want this to happen on either

Comment: @Cris are you using a mac? 
Set a background colour on your content and you won't see the body background behind - See ObsidianAge's answer below

Comment: @itodd your solution worked for me.  I didn't work initially but it was due to other code, which I fixed. Thanks, I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your problem comes from having two types of content; a defined section of content that has its own background colour, and then undefined content sitting directly on the body. I assume it looks something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 1900px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Header content
  <div class="content"></div>
  Footer content
</body>
```

Notice how if I were to change the colour of the 'header', the footer would **also** change colour. You're trying to solve this with a linear gradient, but the problem isn't with the **colour** at all; it's the with **layout**.

What you want to do is break each section of your content up into its own `<div>`. This way, you can style each section **individually**, allowing you to set a different colour for both the header and footer:

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: purple;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Note that if you're able to scroll past the footer on some websites, this may be coming from the fact that mobile phones can 'swing' to the bottom on their scroll effect. This 'extra' content **does not exist**, and is whitespace generated by your phone trying to 'catch up' to where the bottom of the page is.

You can control **that** colour by setting a colour for the `background` attribute directly on `html`. As long as all of your 'actual' content is **overriding** the colour set in `html`, you can set this colour to be whatever you'd like. However, it's really not something that needs to be worried about, and can safely be left as the default white.

Hope this helps! :)